# Are Red Dead Redemption save files on PS3 compatible with the GOTY Edition?

Tags: red-dead-redemption

My brother is getting me a GOTY edition of Red Dead Redemption and I have a vanilla save with a 100 percent.

When I get the game, will the dlc be on the disk and be on my save?

Answer (score 0):

**Save files from the original Red Dead Redemption on PS3 are compatible with the Game of the Year Edition.**

I initially owned the base Red Dead Redemption on PSN before buying a physical copy of the GOTY Edition. I can confirm that my save file transferred between versions without any issue.